# Best way to handle locked/disabled fields on your forms?

Tags: html, forms, user-interface, user-experience

I need users to be able to only edit certain fields on a webform, and not others. This may be due to user privileges, for example.

I'm not sure on the best way to handle this.

1. Set the form attribute to disabled. The problem with this is that disabled fields don't get submitted, so I either need to include hidden form fields, or I need to cater for this in my model (i.e. only update fields that shouldn't get changed)
2. Set the attribute to readonly. Possibly better than the above because these fields automatically get posted
3. Don't use a form field at all - just echo out the var in html. Possibly include a hidden form field or only update fields that shouldnt get changed in the model

I'm not sure on the best way to handle this, both from a UX point of view, and from a general application point of view.

Comment: Are you using any kind of application framework on the server, or is this strictly an HTML-only question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always handle this in your models, at the server side. I do not know if your application will be used publicly? But it's fairly easy to change the required or disabled attributes on the client side to be able to use the form elements.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that you could change the required or disabled attributes on the client side. I still need to show the values though, so I assume the most user friendly way is to just echo them out?

Comment: If you do need to show the values echoing them is a good solution yes.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be #3 or not displaying the form fields at all: if the user can't do anything with them they shouldn't be shown. I'd use a disabled field if there's a way to enable it in the current interaction – a disabled field that can't be enabled in any obvious way is confusing and would lead me to think I'm doing something wrong if I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the disabled/hidden combo solution, i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="name-disabled" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
```

Never had any UX issues doing it this way. But by all means if someone has a better solution, speak up.

Answer (score 0):

From the **UI perspective**, don't show the user anything they don't need to see. Not that there's no place for read-only information, but each bit should be considered to see if it needs to be there in a particular context. Simpler forms lead to less confusion, less user time, and happier users.

This is a matter of opinion, I guess, but I believe that user experience is often given short shrift when it should usually be among the most important design criteria for a form.

From the **code perspective**, you're right, you have to adapt a little. Hidden form fields are certainly a possibility, but they are vulnerable to manipulation—which may or may not be a security concern in your particular case.

Presumably anything that would be submitted via a hidden field is already a known value. You didn't specify which framework, if any, you're working with, but it's probably possible add to (and modify and validate) the submitted form data before it goes to the database. If a user doesn't have permission to alter a field, you can omit it from the form and add the field with its default value before you write it to the database.